# Remaining time in inno-setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using inno-setup and I want to display the remaining time of the installation process. Is there any option to show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [submit a feature request](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfeature.php) for this issue on the Inno Setup homepage and you will get my vote. :-)

Comment: I cast my vote. You didn't need to threaten me with "Tanks"! ;-)

Comment: Now you can do it by using [`CurInstallProgressChanged event`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/issues/51).

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to display the remaining time built into InnoSetup.  A progress bar is displayed during installation (unless you are running silently).
Why do you want the remaining time?

Comment: It's a long installation and I want to show the user the remaining time hold him not to be depressed :)

Comment: I don't know that you're going to find a time function... maybe this can help your depressed installer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182112/what-are-some-funny-loading-statements-to-keep-users-amused